# Using Python to find Mac UUID/Serial Number

Tags: python, macos, uuid

Basically I was planning on tying the computers UUID/Serial number to the key which it is ran with, On windows I found getting the UUID easy enough however I am struggling to get anything for Mac.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

MacOS has a built-in program for accessing this information and you can fetch it with

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Serial Number/ {print $4}'
```

If you explicitly needed this string inside python (and if you're using 3.5+) you could use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) module

```
import subprocess
cmd = "system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Serial Number/ {print $4}'"
result = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, check=True)
serial_number = result.stdout.strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'm getting Mac serials via Python:

```
import subprocess

task = subprocess.Popen(
    ['system_profiler', 'SPHardwareDataType'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)

out, err = task.communicate()

for l in out.split('\n'):
    if 'Serial Number (system)' in l:
        serial_line = l.strip()
        break

serial = serial_line.split(' ')[-1]

print(serial)
```

Edit: I've found a method that is shorter and that I like a lot more than a line split loop.

```py
import json
import subprocess
system_profile_data = subprocess.Popen(
    ['system_profiler', '-json', 'SPHardwareDataType'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
data = json.loads(system_profile_data.stdout.read())
serial = data.get('SPHardwareDataType', {})[0].get('serial_number')
print(serial)
```

A pyobjc way can be found here: https://gist.github.com/pudquick/c7dd1262bd81a32663f0