# How to get UUID on MAC with python command?

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, uuid

I need to find a way to let python get the UUID / Serialnumber (System) on a MAC.

On windows I can use this code:

`HWID = subprocess.check_output('wmic csproduct get uuid').decode().split('\n')[1].strip()`

And then I can check if the value saved in the variable 'HWID' is included in my pastebin, so I can make sure the user has a valid license.

But on MAC I have no idea how I can get the same result?

Comment: You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50708348/using-python-to-find-mac-uuid-serial-number/51562152), it may helps you

Comment: Kinda, for me when I print the HWID reslt in python i see this:

b'xxxxxxxxx'  (x is of course y ID)

But when I manually execute the command in Terminal, I get the result without b' '

Answer (score 0):

```
    cmd = "system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep 'Serial Number' | awk '{print $4}'"
    result = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, check=True)
    #HWID = str(result.stdout.strip())
    HWID = result.stdout.decode().strip()
```

This did it. I used the answer from @jibeeeee and got it to work by adding .decode() to the results command.